# Fitting chords to the opening phrase of the Toccata (and Fugue) in D Minor BWV 565?

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, j-s-bach

What are some of the acceptable ways to harmonize the first one and a half bars of BWV 565? In particular, what are some of the chords that would fit on the the opening A? Neither i nor V seems to fit the movement of the opening gesture.

[image]

Comment: I hear this as all Dm with brief dominants on the C#s, but I'm voting to close as opinion based because there is no 'correct' answer.

Comment: @PiedPiper Is there something out of the ordinary about this post? We routinely field posts about harmonization or interpreting harmony that are inherently opinion-based.

Comment: @Aaron The fact that other opinion-based questions weren't closed doesn't mean that new ones can't. You're welcome to vote to keep it open if you wish. The majority decides.

Comment: There's interesting discussion to be had on why this part of the music can have multiple harmonic interpretations, and what the effect of such ambiguity is. I think maybe OP could rewrite/reword it so that it's less *"what's the answer"* and more *"what is achieved by writing the music in this way"*. At the moment, personally I'm leaning away from VTC for that reason.

Comment: @user45266 The philosophy of Stack Exchange is to answer questions rather than provide a discussion forum.

Comment: @PiedPiper Right, which is why I ask that OP rewrite the question such that the relevant information to be provided would answer the question. I'm just saying that this question has depth to it, it's just not being asked in the right way. "Discussion" may have been a poor choice of wording.

Comment: Interesting that it's supposed to be in key Dm, but there's nothing in the key sig. stating that.

Comment: @Tim This is relatively common for music of this time; check out the notion of "Dorian key signatures."

Comment: @Richard - I considered Dorian - as in key sig. for C major, but the C# foiled that.

Comment: @Tim, the Dorian key signature for BWV 565 is discussed in the Wikipedia entry. See the second paragraph of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toccata_and_Fugue_in_D_minor,_BWV_565#History).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This passage would be harmonized primarily with alternating V and i as shown below. However, while V is the "correct" harmonization of the A octaves, it ruins the effect. Part of what makes this passage so effective is the harmonic ambiguity of the A octave.

[image: Bach Toccata and Fugue opening with Roman numerals]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a harmonic analysis: there's an element of dominant on the first main note, tonic on the second.  That's repeated twice more.  Then there's a definite C♯dim7 (acting as a dominant) to a Dsus4 then D major, all over a tonic pedal.

But no-one in their right mind would add chords to this.  It's all about the gesture. Complete in itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to harmonize these motifs:
As this is always named the toccata in dm I tend to hear a minor chord on the first note. But I also could imagine the dominant: both will work!

a) i - V - i (first half bar)

or

b) V - V7 - i

but you could also hear a) and b) combined.

In a slower tempo you could even hear a more differentiated harmonization by underlaying tonic and dominant chords to the descending scale tones.

The pedal note may be the key: the dominant (VII°7) is set over the tonic.