# What purpose does the third measure of Bach's 'toccata and fugue in d minor' serve?

Tags: chords, harmony, cadence

I'm looking for an explanation on the effect and reasoning of Bach's choices in the third measure of 'toccata and fugue in d minor'. I can only presume its a cadence to resolve the chord built in the end of the second measure (involving the c♯) but I do not know the names of the chords or what type of cadence this is. Does anyone know what Bach is doing here and why?

Measures two and three are:

[image: Toccata and Fugue second and third measures]

Comment: See also [Fitting chords to the opening phrase of the Toccata (and Fugue) in D Minor BWV 565?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/108996/70803).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let's have a bit more context.   We've got V7-I in D minor, three times.  Then a prolonged C♯ dim7 over a D pedal, leading to a final Dm chord with the classic (or rather Baroque :-)  sus4 decoration.

The C♯ dim7 has dominant function.  Think of it as a rootless A7♭9 if you like.  But it's over a tonic pedal.   So we can look at it either as another perfect cadence, or as a massive multi-note appoggiatura delaying the final tonic.

Here's a completely different approach to analysing the piece (but I DO wish youngsters would stop calling everything a 'song'!)   Read it for amusement, if nothing more.
https://spark.parkland.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1118&context=ah

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you find papers like the one you linked? I've tried looking for analysis papers on different compositions before but couldn't find any.

Comment: Well, I found that one by Googling "analysis toccata fugue Dm".  Too obvious?  :-)

Comment: never thought of that. thanks